# Standard practice of Magento 2 extension development

Tags: magento2, extensions

I am developing a Magento 2 extension. When I validate this extension on Magento Market place its giving me some warnings like :

- **Use of protected class members is discouraged.**
- **Property name \"$_resultJsonFactory\" should not be prefixed with an underscore to indicate visibility**

I want to know what could be the best practice to develop any extension in Magento 2 with all standards which allowed in Magento marketplace.

Comment: According to that solution I used all this, But it's stop me to declare protected variable and also they indicates, do not use underscore to indicate visibility when I am using this with protected variable.

Comment: The error you get is probably because you're trying to use the variables directly. Please post your full code so we can help you